# Python Edge Driver Web Automation Help - Cannot find Xpath

Tags: python, pycharm, microsoft-edge

[Inspect Youtube Page Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7JzP.png)
I am new to Python and I am learning how to automate webpages.  I under the basics around using the different locators under the inspect element tab to drive my code.

I have written some basic code to skip youtube ads however I am stuck on finding the correct page element to agree to the privacy policy pop up box in Youtube.  I have used ChroPath to try and find the xpath of the page however there doesn't appear to be one.  I was unable to locate any other page elements and I was wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I can automate the click of the 'I Agree' button?

Python Code:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
driver = Edge(options=options)

driver.get('http://www.youtube.com')

def agree():
    while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/ytd-popup-container/paper-dialog/yt-upsell-dialog-renderer/div/div[3]/div[1]/yt-button-renderer/a/paper-button').click()
            driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.<span class="RveJvd snByac">I agree</span>').click()
        except:
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    agree()
```

Youtube Inspect Element Screeshot is below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inspecting the page elements I overlooked the element of iframe.  After doing some digging I came across the fact I had to tell the Selenium Driver to switch from the main page to the iframe.  I added the following code and now the click to the 'I Agree' button is automated:

frame_element = driver.find_element_by_id('iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_element)
agree2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/c-wiz/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/span/span").click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the xpath in your code is right as I can't see the whole html structure of the page. But you can use F12 dev tools in Edge to find the xpath and to check if the xpath you find is right:

1. Open the page you want to automate and open F12 dev tools in Edge.
2. Use **Ctrl+Shift+C** and click the element you want to locate and find the html code of the element.
3. Right click the html code and select **Copy -> Copy XPath**.
4. Then you can try to use the xpath you copy.

[image]

Besides, `find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)` will return **a list** with elements if any was found. I think you need to specify which one element of the list to click with. You need to pass in the value number of the elements list like this `[x]`, for example:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.<span class="RveJvd snByac">I agree</span>')[0].click()
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I have tried doing that but the xpath which I copied doesn't work which is why I tried to use Chropath which states their is no valid xpath under that page element.  I was trying to find another way of automating the button click.  There is a way of using screen coordinates but i'm not sure if this is the best way?

Comment: I think the best way is to find the element by id, name or xpath. But if it can't work with this way, you can try the screen coordinates way.

Comment: That's great! You can also put your solution as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I done some more digging and another way of selecting the mentioned element was by using the switch to iframe method.  As I am new to Python I wasn't familiar with this method.